# how to find control using name attribute in jquery if the control is a server side control

Tags: jquery

i have a radio button group and want to find the attribute value of which one is checked

i was using the below code which was working fine previously but since i have made the control as a server side control(.net) it is rendering the name attribute differently.

var id = $("input[name=thumbGroup]:checked").attr('value');

**rendered html**

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_piSection_rdUseThubImg" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$piSection$thumbGroup" value="0">
```

Please advice how can i get the value attribute from the above markup using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask what the html structure of the page is..

if you can narrow your filter to a specific section of the page then you can get the checked inputs without knowing the name..

for example lets say the structure is this:

```
<div class="somediv">
    <div class="formsection1">

    </div>
    <div class="formsection2">
       <input id="ctl00_ctl00_piSection_rdUseThubImg" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$piSection$thumbGroup" value="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could do a selector like this:

```
$(".formsection2 input[type=radio]:checked")
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: yeah that should work, but search with name would give me better performance

Comment: It would but as there is no easy way for you to get the name of your .net control you could overcome but changing the formsection2 from a class to an ID (giving a performance improvement?).

Answer (score -1):

You can use ClientID property of a control to get the exact id that get rendered.

So for eg.. if you have a radiobutton named rdUseThubImg, you can use rdUseThubImg.ClientID in the mark up to get its corresponding client side id which equals to ctl00_ctl00_piSection_rdUseThubImg

so in the javascript you can use $("<%= rdUseThubImg.ClientID %>")

more on the client id property.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=VS.85).aspx